# Decide if these 3 vectors are linear independent

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Let $n,p \in \mathbb{N}$ whereby $p$ is a prime number. We have the
>   $n$-th cartesian product $\mathbb{Z}_{p}^{n}=\mathbb{Z}_{p} \times ... \times \mathbb{Z}_{p}$ and
>   an addition / multiplication is defined by:

[image]

We have the vectors

[image]

> Decide if the vectors $v_{1},v_{2}$ and $v_{3}$ as vectors in
>   $\mathbb{Z}_{3}^{3}$ are linear independent.

I wasn't sure if I did it right so that's why I ask. I did this:

$$\begin{pmatrix}
 & (1+1+0) \text{ mod }3 & \\ 
 & (1+0+1) \text{ mod }3 & \\ 
 & (1+0-1) \text{ mod }3 & 
\end{pmatrix}= \begin{pmatrix}
 &2& \\ 
 &2&\\ 
 &0& 
\end{pmatrix}$$

What confuses me is $Z_{3}^{3}$ else I would just have taken $v_{1},v_{2}$ and $v_{3}$, get a linear system and find out if it's linear independent. But what now..?

Comment: Do you remember the definition of linear independence?

Comment: $\lambda$ is supposed to be a scalar in $\mathbb{Z}_3$, right?

Comment: Before I say the definition I need to know If I did it correctly till the last step? Or I completely missunderstood the task? Please do tell me, I might also be able to finish it. Just a YES or NO and if no please a little more details :)

Comment: Yes Arthur right.

Comment: Well, what you did in the last step is not wrong, but I did not quite understand your objective by doing that

Comment: You are verifying their linear (in)depence, so what was your objective when you summed up all the three vectors?

Comment: It would make more sense if I just took the three vectors $v_{1},v_{2},v_{3}$ and check for linear (in)dependence. But the problem is the thing mentioned in the task about the addition and scalar. I somehow have to use it if not it wouldn't be given in the task. Yeah I also ask myself how to check linear (in)dependence if I only got 1 vector as result at the end.. You know how?

Comment: Please let me know if you have any more questions on that @cnmesr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, we want to know whether or not we are capable of expressing the zero vector as a non-trivial linear combination of the vector $v_1,v_2,v_3$, so all we have to do is verify if the only possible solution for the system: 
$$\bar{a} \begin{pmatrix}
\bar{1} \\
\bar{1}\\
\bar{1}\\
\end{pmatrix} + \bar{b} \begin{pmatrix} \bar{1}\\ \bar{0} \\ \bar{0} \end{pmatrix}+\bar{c} \begin{pmatrix} \bar{0} \\ \bar{1} \\ \bar{2}\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} \bar{0} \\ \bar{0} \\ \bar{0}\end{pmatrix}$$

(remember that, in $\mathbb{Z}_3$, $\ \bar{-1}=\bar{2}$), so the system is :

$$\begin{cases} \bar{a}+\bar{b} = \bar{0} \\ \bar{a}+\bar{c} = \bar{0}\\ \bar{a}+\bar{2c}=\bar{0}
\end{cases}$$

So, subtracting the second equation from the third, we get $\bar{c}=\bar{0}$, necessarily, which implies that the only solution ofr the system is indeed the trivial.

Now, as you said, what confused you is the fact that we are dealing with $\mathbb{Z}_3$, otherwise, you would just solve the linear system, probably using Gauss elimination. However, I would like to point out that in any field, Gauss elimination algorithm is well defined, since in a field, all the non-zero elements have inverses. So in this case too, all you have to do is, as you said yourself, "get a linear system".

Comment: Thank you very much, just one question: How do you know that in $Z_{3}, -1 = 2$?

Comment: In $\mathbb{Z}_n$, a number is, in fact a classe of equivalence from the relation $\equiv \mod n$, so $\bar{-1} = \{ m\in \mathbb{Z} | m \equiv -1 \mod n \}$. So in $\mathbb{Z}_3$, $\bar{-1}=\bar{2}$. (can you see why now?) @cnmesr